# Why $\cos(t-s)$ is a "positive function"?

Tags: probability, covariance

**Problem:** Let $c: \mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be a finite support function, i.e. the set $\{t: c(t)\neq 0\}$ is finite. Prove that
\begin{align}\label{eq1}
\sum_{t, s\in \mathbb R} c(t)c(s) \cos(t-s)\geq 0.
\end{align}

**Reason:** The reason I ask this question is because $\cos(s-t)$ can be considered as a covariance function (see the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3661984/covariance-function-of-a-gaussian-process-sin-and-cos)). And we know that every covariance function is positive (in the sense that above inequality holds for all finite support functions). However, I don't know how to prove above inequality independently. Could anyone give me a hint, thank you!

Comment: Expand the cosine using the addition formula.  Then your result can be written  as the sum of two squares.

Comment: You need to clarify some things: First, when you write the sum, do you mean an integral? Sums are usually defined over the integers or some countable set. 

Secondly, you surely need some assumptions on the function c. It needs to be integrable (or at least its product with cos needs to be integrable), and maybe you want it to be bounded?

Comment: @RichardJensen ... note that $c$ has finite support.  No assumptions beyond that.  It is a sum, not an integral.

Comment: @GEdgar, many thanks for your hint. But to me, it seems not easy to get the "sum of squares", could you please give me a further hint?

$c(t)c(s)\cos(t-s)=0.5 (c(t)\cos(t)+c(s)\cos(s))^2 +0.5(c(t)\sin(t)-c(s)\sin(s))^2-0.5(c(t)^2+c(s)^2)$ and what I should do next?

Comment: @RichardJensen many thanks for your comment!

Comment: @GEdgar Oooh, you're right, I was thinking about compact support and my brain assumed it ment the support was a bounded set!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{s,t} c(s)c(t)\cos(s-t) &= 
\sum_{s,t}\big(c(s)c(t)\cos(s)\cos(t)+c(s)c(t)\sin(s)\sin(t)\big)
\\ &=
\left(\sum_s c(s)\cos(s)\right)^2 + \left(\sum_s c(s)\sin(s)\right)^2 \ge 0.
\end{align}

Comment: Ah ok, I should consider the sum instead of its components, thank you so much!